# Elastic beanstalk nginx redirect setting not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to redirect http to https and I have this config:

```
files:
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/robots.conf":
        mode: "000544"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            server {
                listen 80;

                server_name example.com;

                location =/health {
                    return 200 "health-check";
                }

                location / {
                    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
                        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
                    }
                }
            }
            server {
                listen 80 default_server;

                server_name www.example.com;

                location =/health {
                    return 200 "health-check";
                }

                location / {
                    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
                        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
                    }
                }
            }
```

But when I go to http://example.com or http://www.example.com there is no redirect...
I've tried multiple settings but it seems like it never fully works.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is set your config as below

```
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    my.example.com;
       return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
       listen         443 ssl;
       server_name    my.example.com;
       # add Strict-Transport-Security to prevent man in the middle attacks
       add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"; 

       [....]
}
```

Comment: Did you reload the config with `service nginx reload` ?

Comment: No, Im just commiting and deploying using  `eb deploy`, where would I put `service nginx reload`? Or do you mean I should ssh into the instance and do that?